# How to remove separator line under sherlock actionbar tab bar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have added actionbar tabs like this:

```
mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 
mDayTab = mActionBar.newTab(); 
mDayTab.setIcon(R.drawable.tabicon_home);
mDayTab.setTabListener(this); 
mActionBar.addTab(mDayTab);
```

Theme styles:

```
    <style name="Theme.Sherlock.Light.Custom" parent="Sherlock.__Theme.Light">

        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/customTabView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/customTabView</item>

    </style>

    <style name="customTabView" parent="Widget">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StyleTitleTextColor" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/setTitleTextColor</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/setTitleTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="setTitleTextColor" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

I have used this to make tabs part of activity layout.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

But still it shows a thin white divider under tab bar. How can I remove this?
Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want to remove that white line that is indicated in image with arrow tip.

Comment: kifak Adnan, just tell me one thing, is `android:showDividers` changing anything? If yes, what is it changing exactly?

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: do they have transparent background?

Comment: tab images are png images, created with transparent background. But images doesn't contain any blank area around them.